# Java Splitting a string with multiple delimiters, some of which are 2-character sequences

Tags: java, regex, string, split

long-time reader here but first-time poster!  I am working on a college project that involves using Java to manipulate transcriptions of traditional music melodies written in the text-based abc notation standard (see [here](http://trillian.mit.edu/~jc/doc/doc/ABCprimer.html) for a quick explainer on the abc standard, if you are interested).

I want to take the body of a whole tune transcription which is represented as a String, and split it into individual bars (i.e. into an array of Strings, one String for each bar).  The abc standard has a number of different [symbols and combinations of symbols](http://abcnotation.com/wiki/abc:standard:v2.1#repeat_bar_symbols) that are used to delimit bars.  These symbols are:

```
|   
|]  
||  
[|  
|:  
:|  
::
```

My idea was to use a regular expression with the String.split() method to break the `tuneBody` String below into the `arrayOfBars` array of Strings.  My regex is below, and is intended to try to find any of the above symbols that can be used to delimit a bar in the music.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TroubleshootRegex 
{
    //Split the tuneBody into individual bars
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
        //The musical notes from an abc tune transcription
        String tuneBody = "|:G3 GAB|A3 ABd|edd gdd|edB dBA|\nGAG GAB|ABA ABd|edd gdd|BAF G3:|\nB2B d2d|ege dBA|B2B dBG|ABA AGA|\nBAB d^cd|ege dBd|gfg aga|bgg g3:|";        

        //The body of the tune after being split into individual bars
        String[] arrayOfBars;

        //This regex is my attempt to look for all the possible bar delimiters defined in the abc standard
        String abcBarDelimiters = "[\\|]|\\|\\||\\[\\||\\|:|:\\||::|\\|]";
        arrayOfBars = tuneBody.split(abcBarDelimiters);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayOfBars));
        }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run the above, I end up with a couple of issues.  One of the issues is that I get an empty string at the start of the array, but a bit of research shows me that that's a known issue so I'll figure out a way to work around that.  The bigger issue though that I can't seem to figure out on my own is that I end up with a colon included in the first bar of the music, whereas this *should* be filtered out as part of the initial delimiter when splitting the string if everything worked as intended. i.e. I want the initial "|:" delimiter from `tuneBody` to be removed during the string splitting.  Here's the output:

```
[, :G3 GAB, A3 ABd, edd gdd, edB dBA,   
GAG GAB, ABA ABd, edd gdd, BAF G3,   
B2B d2d, ege dBA, B2B dBG, ABA AGA,   
BAB d^cd, ege dBd, gfg aga, bgg g3]
```

I'm assuming that means that I probably have some kind of problem in my regex, but for the life of me I can't seem to figure out what the actual problem is, and I'm starting to go cross-eyed looking at it!  It seems that it is matching the single pipe character at the start as a delimiter, rather than matching the character sequence |:

I'd be massively grateful if anyone who actually knows a bit about regexes can tell me why mine doesn't seem to do what I want, or how to get it to see the |: sequence as a whole as a delimiter, rather than a delimiter followed by a colon.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try [`String abcBarDelimiters = "\\[\\||\\|[:|\\]]|:[:|]|\\|";`](https://ideone.com/uYk8ZA). Does it yield the expected output?

Comment: You have saved me from tearing my hair out.  Thank you sir.  Now I just need to figure out why yours works and mine doesn't ;-)

Comment: Btw, the page you linked states `Abc parsers should be quite liberal in recognizing bar lines. In the wild, bar lines may have any shape, using a sequence of | (thin bar line), [ or ] (thick bar line), and : (dots), e.g. |[| or [|::: .` - that means using regular expressions might not be ideal for that task. It seems as if delimiters like `:|:` or `[|]` might also be allowed, so if your data _could_ contain those your expression might end up being way too complex and still not complete.

Comment: @Thomas, yes I read that section myself, but from my own knowledge of abc notation most of the tune sources I use contain the standard bar lines, and this project is an academic exercise for myself rather than for general public use, so I'm not overly worried about it at the moment.  If I have the free time at the end of the project I might go back and look at adding a routine of some sort to catch non-standard bar lines and replace them with the standard forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One of the issues is that I get an empty string at the start of the array, but a bit of research shows me that that's a known issue so I'll figure out a way to work around that.

The problem is that your string starts with a delimiter so it will create an empty string as the first element of the split. The same would happen if you have two consecutive delimiters, e.g. `...|::|...`. To solve that you could remove the empty strings you don't want, e.g. by using a list instead of an array.

> The bigger issue though that I can't seem to figure out on my own is that I end up with a colon included in the first bar of the music, whereas this should be filtered out as part of the initial delimiter when splitting the string if everything worked as intended. i.e. I want the initial "|:" delimiter from tuneBody to be removed during the string splitting.

I'm not entirely sure here (but pretty sure): the problem is that the single pipe is the first option in your regex and thus it matches the pipe in `|:`. To fix that it should be sufficient to put the single pipe at the end.

You can also simplify your regex since you don't need character classes. Thus this should work:

```
String abcBarDelimiters = "\\|\\||\\[\\||\\|:|:\\||::|\\|\\]|\\|";
```

Comment: You may use character classes to shrink the pattern a bit, to make it work faster: `String abcBarDelimiters = "\\[\\||\\|[:|\\]]|:[:|]|\\|";`

Comment: I don´t know if i did miss anything, but from my point of view using character classes would be better to read (getting rid of all these `\\ `).
regex as : `"[:][:|]|[|][\\]|:]|[\\[][|]|\\|"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes you could use those provided that you know what they do - which I'm not sure of in the OP's case (yet).

Comment: @KevinEsche yes it looks more readable at least due to less escaping - but to be honest that expression is still painful to read ;) - The problem is that the OP might not be comfortable reading parts like `...|[|]...` so after all the original version might be more readable for him.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I'm slowly getting to grips with Wiktor's answer by pasting \\[\\||\\|[:|\\]]|:[:|]|\\| here http://xenon.stanford.edu/~xusch/regexp/ and looking at the output.  I suppose I need to go learn more about regular expressions which I have generally avoided until now!

Answer (score 0):

For going more easy on the regex beginners eyes, try the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    //The musical notes from an abc tune transcription
    String tuneBody = "|:G3 GAB|A3 ABd|edd gdd|edB dBA|\nGAG GAB|ABA ABd|edd gdd|BAF G3:|\nB2B d2d|ege dBA|B2B dBG|ABA AGA|\nBAB d^cd|ege dBd|gfg aga|bgg g3:|";        

    //The body of the tune after being split into individual bars

    String re1 = "\\|[\\]\\||:]?";  // |, |], |:
    String re2 = "\\[\\|";          // [|
    String re3 = ":[\\|:]";         // :|, ::

    String abcBarDelimiters = "(" + re1 + "|" + re2 + "|" + re3 + ")";

    String[] arrayOfBars = tuneBody.split(abcBarDelimiters);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayOfBars));
}
```

... and as Thomas already said, the empty string at the beginning is due to the input starting with a delimiter.

Comment: No, ? is greedy, ?? would be reluctant. This works as expected.